# Sequel gem: Create tables based on schema provided at runtime

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel

The title might be a bit misleading or broad, but what I am trying to do is to provide the necessary data for the sequel gem to create a table. Sequel's syntax for creating tables is the following

```
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end
```

For my particular case the column type and name are provided by the user, so I can only do it at runtime. For the time being I am accepting an array of column_name:column_type pairs, like so for instance:

```
['column1:string', 'column2:float']
```

but I am having a hard time yielding this information to the above block. My current attempt is:

```
my_db.create_table 'my_table' do
      array_of_typed_columns.each do |tc|
        column, type = tc.split(':')
        type.capitalize.constantize; column.to_sym
      end
    end
```

My understanding is that the above code would result in consecutive `Type symbolized_column_name` expressions yielded to the table creation block, but I always end up with a table with no columns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSL where a line begins with a word, and then a list of parameters with a coma between them is actually a method call, so the original code is actually:

```
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key(:id)
  String(:name)
  Float(:price)
end
```

From the sequel [documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html):

> Most method calls inside the `create_table` block will create columns,
>   since `method_missing` calls column. Columns are generally created by
>   specifying the column type as the method name, followed by the column
>   name symbol to use, and after that any options that should be used. If
>   the method is a ruby class name that Sequel recognizes, Sequel will
>   transform it into the appropriate type for the given database. So
>   while you specified `String`, Sequel will actually use `varchar` or `text`
>   depending on the underlying database.

The `create_table` block uses `method_missing` to find out what you are trying to say. So what you could try to do is use `send` instead:

```
my_db.create_table 'my_table' do
  array_of_typed_columns.each do |tc|
    column, type = tc.split(':')
    send(type.capitalize, column.to_sym)
  end
end
```